Using LaunchDarkly's React Web SDK, is there a way to send a context as a request body, rather than URI
I'm set up with LaunchDarkly's React Web SDK in my app, and it works fine for small contexts. But I need to send a very large context with a lot of data, which cannot be done the default way in the URI (I get a 414 HTTP error).
I've read that it seems the way to get around this is to send the context as part of the request body, but I can't seem to find a way to do it with the React Web SDK. I've tried sending the context as part of a call to identify, after initialization, but it still puts the context in the URI.
It seems like I may be able to use the rest API in tandem with the React SDK, but would require me to implement some extra safeguards and data sync. What is the easiest way to send a very large context?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's not a code question, it's a question of which SDK/API or toolkit to use.

Try using Launchdarkly REST API. They provided Create or update context kind.
https://apidocs.launchdarkly.com/tag/Contexts#operation/putContextKind
